# excel vba shifting formulas based on sales lead time

Tags: excel, vba

I trying to find the correct code to move my formulas over x number of cells.  The x would represent sales lead time.  Lets say I make a January sale, but that revenue wont actually be received until 7 months later.  So for Jan I wont receive until July, for Feb I wont receive until August, for March I wont receive until September and so on.

I'm looking for something to automate or shift my formulas that total my sales over based on a lead time cell.  So lets say I change my lead time to 5 months everything shifts over to reflect 5 months instead of 7.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Hope thats not too confusing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I suspect this could be done with formulas without "Shifting" anything from one cell to another. It's impossible to say though since we have no idea what your sheet looks like. We don't know what it means to "receive revenue" for "July" that was made in "January". Can you share a picture of your sheet and explain what numbers are to go where, or a seperate picture with your desired results when shifted for 5 months... I suspect though that the formula `=INDIRECT()` may help out quite a bit here.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking at the problem from the wrong end: Instead of asking when your January sales proceeds will be received, try asking which proceeds you will receive in July. Then you arrive at a structure like this:-

```
Column A = Date of sale
Column B = Description
Column C = Sales amount
Column D = Expected delay in months
Column E and up = Jan, Feb, etc. one column for each month

Write the starting date in cell E1, say 1/1/2017.
In F1 paste this formula: =DATE(YEAR(E1),MONTH(E1)+1,1)
Format the range E1:F1 as 'Custom' using the string MMM yy
Copy F1 to the right as far into the future as you require
```

Now you have a column for each month. If you change the value in E1 all captions will change accordingly. That's good when you need a new sheet for next year.

```
Write this formula in E2: =IF(MONTH($A2) + $D2 = MONTH(E$1), $C2,0)
Copy right and down as far as you require
```

Now, make an entry. Say on Jan 17 you had a sale of $1200 and you expect to receive the money 6 months later.

```
Enter the date in column A = 17/1/2017
Enter the amount in column C = 1200
Enter the expected delay in column D = 6
```

The amount appears in the July column. Change the value in column D to 3 and the amount moves to April.

All the other columns show a zero. If you don't like that, go to File ->Options -> Advanced >>Display options for this worksheet = uncheck the checkbox for "Show a zero in cells that have zero value".